# call a regular MVC controller method from a webapi2 service

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

Given an **MVC controller method**, that builds and returns a **PDF**.

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("pdf/{acc}/{sign}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Download(string acc, string sign)
    {
        ... // omitted some irrelevant detail.
        var html = this.View("Letter", model).Capture(this.ControllerContext);
        byte[] pdf = this.CreatePdfFromHtml(html);
        return this.File(binary, "application/pdf", file);
    }
```

The `Capture` extension method captures the `html` output, which is then returned as a file.

I need to execute the above method (or something close) in **the below webapi2 method**.
I need the credentials and other login state to be present. The webapi and MVC requests are within the same application that uses cookies for security.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("generate")]
    public int Generate(MyRequestModel request)
    {
        byte[] pdf = ... // how do i get the file above??
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either *request* the MVC action via `HttpClient` or simply factor out the PDF creation into a helper class that both your MVC and Web Api actions can reference.

With the first method, you would need to some how authenticate the request, which is going to be a bit difficult to do with an MVC action. MVC uses a multi-step authorization: sign in, verify, set cookie, redirect. You would have to follow those same steps in order to get a cookie set via `HttpClient`. Think of it as a little mini-browser. Web Api, on the other hand, simply accepts an `Authorization` header, since API requests are idempotent.

The easiest and most straight-forward route, especially since both your MVC and Web Api reside in the same application, would be to simply factor out the PDF creation code into a helper class. Your MVC and Web Api actions, then, can simply just call some method on that class to get the PDF, reducing code duplication.

Comment: Thanks Chris - problem is that's the PDF is generated by capturing HTML from an mvc view, so factoring out the PDF generation code is exactly the problem. I might have to go with creating a client - which does seem like a lot of hoops....

Comment: I think I will just call a regular MVC method from angular, it's really just for consistency that I want to use webapi.